# How to limit the amount of input into an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

Hi everyone I am still relatively new to Java and I was just wondering if anyone could help me with limiting the amount of times the user can input. As you can see right now the user can input unlimited times can anyone help me limit that to "n" times?

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int check=192;
while(true){
    check = input.nextInt();
    if(check == 192) break;
    al.add(check);
}

for (int i : al) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Comment: This is an ArrayList, not an array. They can grow indefinitely (not really, but large enough). Arrays are of fixed-size.

Comment: You need a counter variable.

Comment: `while(al.size() < N)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare counter before while loop and then increment counter after every input.

```
int count = 0;
int limit = x; // you declare how many times
while(true && count < x){
    // your code
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Why keeping the `true` condition in the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
   check = input.nextInt();
   al.add(check);
}
```